# kendo ui core entity framework core undefined in kendoMultiSelect

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, kendo-ui

**UI looks like this**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="kMultiSelect" data-placeholder="Select Traits..." />
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    var dataSourceTraits = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "api/Traits",
                dataType: "json"
            },
            create: {
                url: "api/Traits",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",

                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                    }
                }
            },
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                ID: "Trait",
                fields: {
                    ID: { type: "number" },
                    UID: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    $("#kMultiSelect").kendoMultiSelect({
        autoBind: true,
        dataTextField: "UID",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        dataSource: dataSourceTraits
    });
</script>
```

**Model**

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string UID { get; set; }
    .....
```

**Controller**

```
 // GET: api/Traits
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Trait> GetTrait()
    {

        // var test = _context.Trait;

        return _context.Trait;
    }
```

I have 4 rows in my table and I get 4 rows in the kendoMultiSelect each row just has "undefined" for text.

[Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7y6U7.png)

thanks for the help

Comment: Remove `dataType: "json"` from read and try once.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately I get the same result (four rows of undefined)

Answer (score 0):

after more help, entity framework core, by default, returns json.  this datasource works

```
    var dataSourceTraits = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        type: "json",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "api/Traits"

            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    id: { type: "number" },
                    name: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```